# How to wrap shell commands via ssh?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins v2.375.1

I usually use the [SSH Agent Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) to wrap my Git commands, like this

```
sshagent(credentialsId: ["my-ssh-credentials"]) {
  sh """
    git tag some_tag
    git push origin some_tag
  """
}
```

But it seems like the latest version of the plugin is broken again (see [issues](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/issues/)). I see

```
+ which ssh-agent
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
[Pipeline] dir
Running in c:\jenkins\workspace\test\test-ssh
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials software.development@company.com (my-ssh-credentials)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ ssh-agent
[ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
[ssh-agent] Diagnostic report
[ssh-agent] * Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
```

With this in mind, how can I execute my `shell` commands wrapped in `ssh`? TIA

Comment: It is not feasible to rollback to the previous version?

Comment: Thanks. I rolled back to a version that I knew worked, but that doesn't work either. It's probably another plugin that affected it.